# I need to pick single value from an attribute using xslt 1.0

Tags: xml, xslt

Below is the xml.Above that is the code that I have tried to use to pick the first ReportDate attribute from the first DayList node that comes up and assign it to $reportDate. I can't get it to work unfortunately. Any ideas?

```
<xsl:variable name ="reportDate">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="ReportGroup/LOB"></xsl:apply-templates>
    </xsl:variable>
      <xsl:template match="ReportGroup/LOB">    
            <xsl:value-of select="List/DayList[@ReportDate][1]" />  
    </xsl:template>`enter code here`

<ReportGroup ReportName="UIP Coll Bankcard CAU" ReportNameMasterID="3622">
    <LOB LOBMasterID="8613" GroupName="Bankcard UPP Completer Callbacks">
      <List ListName="[ALM4] MQYC_UPP_BP_CP_A4">
        <MtdList ReportDate="02/05/2015" DateType="MTD" Multipass="13" />
      </List>
      <List ListName="[ALM4] MQYC_UPP_BP_ONLY_A4">
        <MtdList ReportDate="02/05/2015" DateType="MTD" Multipass="14" />
      </List>
    </LOB>
    <LOB LOBMasterID="8612" GroupName="Bankcards CompleterPre-Del">
      <List ListName="[ALM4] MQYC_UPP_HP_BP_A4">
        <MtdList ReportDate="02/05/2015" DateType="MTD" Multipass="27" />
      </List>
      <List ListName="[ALM4] MQYC_UPP_HP_BP_CP_A4">
        <MtdList ReportDate="02/05/2015" DateType="MTD" Multipass="1" />
      </List>
      <List ListName="[ALM4] MQYC_UPP_HP_CP_A4">
        <MtdList ReportDate="02/05/2015" DateType="MTD" Multipass="18" />
      </List>
      <List ListName="[ALM4] MQYC_UPP_HP_ONLY_A4">
        <MtdList ReportDate="02/05/2015" DateType="MTD" Multipass="52" />
      </List>
      <List ListName="[ALM4] MQYC_UPP_Verified_CP_ONLY_A4">
        <MtdList ReportDate="02/05/2015" DateType="MTD" Multipass="67" />
      </List>
    </LOB>
    <LOB LOBMasterID="8617" GroupName="Best Buy CAU">
      <List ListName="[ALM2] MP7C_PXPZ_BP_CP_A2">
        <DayList ReportDate="02/08/2015" DateType="Day" Multipass="1" />
        <MtdList ReportDate="02/08/2015" DateType="MTD" Multipass="13" />
      </List>
      <List ListName="[ALM2] MP7C_PXPZ_BP_ONLY_A2">
        <DayList ReportDate="02/08/2015" DateType="Day" Multipass="1" />
        <MtdList ReportDate="02/08/2015" DateType="MTD" Multipass="1" />
      </List>
      <List ListName="[ALM2] MP7C_PXPZ_HP_BP_A2">
        <MtdList ReportDate="02/02/2015" DateType="MTD" Multipass="1" />
      </List>
      <List ListName="[ALM2] MP7C_PXPZ_HP_BP_CP_A2">
        <DayList ReportDate="02/08/2015" DateType="Day" Multipass="0" />
        <MtdList ReportDate="02/08/2015" DateType="MTD" Multipass="0" />
      </List>
      <List ListName="[ALM2] MP7C_PXPZ_HP_CP_A2">
        <DayList ReportDate="02/08/2015" DateType="Day" Multipass="1" />
        <MtdList ReportDate="02/08/2015" DateType="MTD" Multipass="30" />
      </List>
      <List ListName="[ALM2] MP7C_PXPZ_HP_ONLY_A2">
        <DayList ReportDate="02/08/2015" DateType="Day" Multipass="4" />
        <MtdList ReportDate="02/08/2015" DateType="MTD" Multipass="52" />
      </List>
      <List ListName="[ALM2] MP7C_PXPZ_Verified_CP_ONLY_A2">
        <DayList ReportDate="02/08/2015" DateType="Day" Multipass="11" />
        <MtdList ReportDate="02/08/2015" DateType="MTD" Multipass="59" />
      </List>
    </LOB>
    <LOB LOBMasterID="8608" GroupName="Bucket 1-5 PX_PZ">
      <List ListName="[ALM4] MPBC_PX_PZ_BP_CP_A4">
        <DayList ReportDate="02/08/2015" DateType="Day" Multipass="11" />
        <MtdList ReportDate="02/08/2015" DateType="MTD" Multipass="110" />
      </List>
      <List ListName="[ALM4] MPBC_PX_PZ_BP_ONLY_A4">
        <DayList ReportDate="02/08/2015" DateType="Day" Multipass="1" />
        <MtdList ReportDate="02/08/2015" DateType="MTD" Multipass="48" />
      </List>
      <List ListName="[ALM4] MPBC_PX_PZ_HP_BP_A4">
        <DayList ReportDate="02/08/2015" DateType="Day" Multipass="6" />
        <MtdList ReportDate="02/08/2015" DateType="MTD" Multipass="141" />
      </List>
      <List ListName="[ALM4] MPBC_PX_PZ_HP_BP_CP_A4">
        <DayList ReportDate="02/08/2015" DateType="Day" Multipass="5" />
        <MtdList ReportDate="02/08/2015" DateType="MTD" Multipass="44" />
      </List>
      <List ListName="[ALM4] MPBC_PX_PZ_HP_CP_A4">
        <DayList ReportDate="02/08/2015" DateType="Day" Multipass="12" />
        <MtdList ReportDate="02/08/2015" DateType="MTD" Multipass="131" />
      </List>
      <List ListName="[ALM4] MPBC_PX_PZ_HP_ONLY_A4">
        <DayList ReportDate="02/08/2015" DateType="Day" Multipass="29" />
        <MtdList ReportDate="02/08/2015" DateType="MTD" Multipass="440" />
      </List>
      <List ListName="[ALM4] MPBC_PX_PZ_Verified_CP_ONLY_A4">
        <DayList ReportDate="02/08/2015" DateType="Day" Multipass="8" />
        <MtdList ReportDate="02/08/2015" DateType="MTD" Multipass="136" />
      </List>
    </LOB>
    <LOB LOBMasterID="8601" GroupName="Buckets 1-5 Manual">
      <List ListName="[ALM4] MPBM_DU_BP_CP_A4">
        <DayList ReportDate="02/08/2015" DateType="Day" Multipass="2" />
        <MtdList ReportDate="02/08/2015" DateType="MTD" Multipass="16" />
      </List>
      <List ListName="[ALM4] MPBM_DU_BP_ONLY_A4">
        <DayList ReportDate="02/08/2015" DateType="Day" Multipass="2" />
        <MtdList ReportDate="02/08/2015" DateType="MTD" Multipass="16" />
      </List>
      <List ListName="[ALM4] MPBM_DU_HP_BP_A4">
        <DayList ReportDate="02/08/2015" DateType="Day" Multipass="5" />
        <MtdList ReportDate="02/08/2015" DateType="MTD" Multipass="38" />
      </List>
      <List ListName="[ALM4] MPBM_DU_HP_CP_A4">
        <DayList ReportDate="02/08/2015" DateType="Day" Multipass="5" />
        <MtdList ReportDate="02/08/2015" DateType="MTD" Multipass="32" />
      </List>
      <List ListName="[ALM4] MPBM_DU_HP_ONLY_A4">
        <DayList ReportDate="02/08/2015" DateType="Day" Multipass="13" />
        <MtdList ReportDate="02/08/2015" DateType="MTD" Multipass="114" />
      </List>
      <List ListName="[ALM4] MPBM_DU_Verified_CP_ONLY_A4">
        <DayList ReportDate="02/08/2015" DateType="Day" Multipass="18" />
        <MtdList ReportDate="02/08/2015" DateType="MTD" Multipass="126" />
      </List>
    </LOB>
    <LOB LOBMasterID="8680" GroupName="Sears CAU">
      <List ListName="[ALM2] MPSC_PXPZ_BP_CP_A2">
        <DayList ReportDate="02/08/2015" DateType="Day" Multipass="2" />
        <MtdList ReportDate="02/08/2015" DateType="MTD" Multipass="8" />
      </List>
      <List ListName="[ALM2] MPSC_PXPZ_BP_ONLY_A2">
        <MtdList ReportDate="02/05/2015" DateType="MTD" Multipass="1" />
      </List>
      <List ListName="[ALM2] MPSC_PXPZ_HP_BP_A2">
        <DayList ReportDate="02/08/2015" DateType="Day" Multipass="2" />
        <MtdList ReportDate="02/08/2015" DateType="MTD" Multipass="16" />
      </List>
      <List ListName="[ALM2] MPSC_PXPZ_HP_BP_CP_A2">
        <MtdList ReportDate="02/07/2015" DateType="MTD" Multipass="2" />
      </List>
      <List ListName="[ALM2] MPSC_PXPZ_HP_CP_A2">
        <DayList ReportDate="02/08/2015" DateType="Day" Multipass="15" />
        <MtdList ReportDate="02/08/2015" DateType="MTD" Multipass="131" />
      </List>
      <List ListName="[ALM2] MPSC_PXPZ_HP_ONLY_A2">
        <DayList ReportDate="02/08/2015" DateType="Day" Multipass="42" />
        <MtdList ReportDate="02/08/2015" DateType="MTD" Multipass="431" />
      </List>
      <List ListName="[ALM2] MPSC_PXPZ_Verified_CP_ONLY_A2">
        <DayList ReportDate="02/08/2015" DateType="Day" Multipass="18" />
        <MtdList ReportDate="02/08/2015" DateType="MTD" Multipass="154" />
      </List>
      <List ListName="[ALM2] MPSM_DU_HP_ONLY_A2">
        <DayList ReportDate="02/08/2015" DateType="Day" Multipass="2" />
        <MtdList ReportDate="02/08/2015" DateType="MTD" Multipass="18" />
      </List>
      <List ListName="[ALM2] MPSM_DU_Verified_CP_ONLY_A2">
        <DayList ReportDate="02/08/2015" DateType="Day" Multipass="2" />
        <MtdList ReportDate="02/08/2015" DateType="MTD" Multipass="10" />
      </List>
    </LOB>
  </ReportGroup>
```

`enter code here`

Answer (score 1):

I think you simply want to use `<xsl:variable name="reportDate" select="(ReportGroup/LOB/List/DayList/@ReportDate)[1]"/>` as that takes the first `ReportDate` attribute found.